# Koa - TypeError: Middleware stack must be an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, middleware, koa

I have router created with `koa-router`:

**auth.js**

```
const KoaRouter = require('koa-router');

const { signIn, signUp } = require('../controllers/auth');

const authRouter = new KoaRouter();

authRouter.post('/signin', signIn).post('/signup', signUp);

module.exports = authRouter;
```

And I want to use it as middleware in my main app. In express, I can just write `app.use(authRouter)`. But Koa said that the middleware should be a function. I find a solution for that and used `koa-mount` package to solve that problem like this `app.use(mount(authRouter))`. But now it gives this error:

> if (!Array.isArray(middleware)) throw new TypeError('Middleware stack
> must be an array!')
> ^
>
> TypeError: Middleware stack must be an array!

But when I log the `authRouter` the stack property is array of routes:

```
Router {
  opts: {},
  methods:
   [ 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'GET', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE' ],
  params: {},
  stack:
   [ Layer {
       opts: [Object],
       name: null,
       methods: [Array],
       paramNames: [],
       stack: [Array],
       path: '/signin',
       regexp: /^\/signin[\/#\?]?$/i },
     Layer {
       opts: [Object],
       name: null,
       methods: [Array],
       paramNames: [],
       stack: [Array],
       path: '/signup',
       regexp: /^\/signup[\/#\?]?$/i } ] }
```

Here is the whole code:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const KoaRouter = require('koa-router');
const mount = require('koa-mount');
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');

const config = require('./config');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');

const app = new Koa();
const router = new KoaRouter();

console.log(authRoutes);
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());
app.use(mount(authRoutes));

app.listen(config.PORT || 3001);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just missing calling `.routes()` on your `authRoutes` object.

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const KoaRouter = require('koa-router');
const mount = require('koa-mount');
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser');

const config = require('./config');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');

const app = new Koa();
const router = new KoaRouter();

console.log(authRoutes);
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());
// add this line 
app.use(authRoutes.routes()).use(authRoutes.allowedMethods());

app.listen(config.PORT || 3001);
```